# Nullable<int> id in LINQ to SQL relationships

Tags: c#, database

I use LINQ to SQL queries to communicate with a database from my Visual C# application. I'm using *Deferred Loading* (seen on [How to: Map Database Relationships (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386950%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). I use the `ColumnAttribute` to define the Mapping as follows:

```
[Column(Storage = "id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, CanBeNull=false)]
    public Nullable<int> Id {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id = value; }
    }
```

I want to give the database full control over the Id's of the table entries and the corresponding relations (foreign keys). When I add a new entry, I want the Id's of all relational tables to be *null* until they are inserted into the database by `DataContext.SubmitChanges()` at which point the database will create all Id's.

**My question:** I have seen different cases where the Id is set nullable in C# and others not. What is the better way to do?

Comment: What you want `When I add a new entry, I want the Id's of all relational tables to be null until they are inserted into the database by DataContext.SubmitChanges()` is not how Entity Framework works.  If it's an Seeded Int, the default value will be 0 (Zero).  That's is how the framework is designed, if this doesn't work for you, I suggest not using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'll just use an int not a `Nullable<int>`.  In fact, SQL Server prohibits nullable primary keys and identities.  You can tell the EntityFramework if an object is new by setting the State of the entity within the DbContext to EntityState.Added.  Here's an example from an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) that shows this approach:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blog = new Blog { Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 
    context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Added; 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Once you've set the State to EntityState.Added the EntityFramework and SQL Server will handle the rest of the process by inserting the new record in the database and assigning the appropriate value to the identity field.  The process of setting the State is actually handled implicitly by the EntityFramework when you call the Add() method on a [DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), so you don't have to actually do this explicitly.

Comment: Does this work?  I was pretty sure you had to `context.Blogs.Add(blog);` to add it to the in-memory table (which automatically marks the entity as `Added`.

Comment: When you call context.Blogs.Add(blog) the EntityFramework is actually setting the State property of the entry to EntityState.Added. So, there's no real reason to do this manually, but I wanted to illustrate the concept of what the EF is actually doing.